# Why can't I close vote a question becaues it shows no efforts from OP?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31514449/860421) question, where the OP just asks about solution. He/she hasn't done any efforts, as even searching on the Internet gives a lot of solutions. I tried close voting, but I didn't find any reason similar to the above. I had to choose a different reason to vote. I know others can comment to ask OP post his/her own efforts, but it looks like the comments have not been replied to at all.

Comment: That is about the oldest question on Stack Overflow, similar to "If God exists, why does he allow the horrible suffering on earth?" in religion. :)

Comment: @Pekka웃 I agree but that question didn't show up in 'similar questions' list :-/ .

Comment: Not showing research effort isn't and never has been a close reason. Some people have in the past though used closed reasons for that purpose, those close reasons have since been changed/removed.

Comment: "Too broad" or "unclear" typically apply.

Answer (score 8):

Because "shows no effort" is not a reason to close a question, it's a reason to downvote it. If there's not enough information to answer the question, post a comment asking the OP for more details and close for that reason. Don't just pick a different reason because the one you want isn't there.

Comment: That is a hostile attitude, aparrently: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31642098/758133

Comment: There are comments on that particular question, not a single one attended by the OP. This leads to unanswered stale questions, seemingly the OP hasn't even bothered to see it again. Such questions, I wouldn't want to keep if the site were mine. All I can do on a community driven site is 'vote to close'.

Comment: @0xc0de Then vote to close for that reason, like I said.

Comment: @0xc0de Downvote it and move on, it'l eventually get deleted if it is negatively scored with no answers. No need to waste a close vote on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can downvote the question as "does not include search efforts".

If you hover your mouse over the downvote button for question, then its clearly appealing  "HIT ME", if "This question does not show any research efforts; it is unclear or not useful".

You can also choose "Unclear what are you asking" or "too broad" as Close reason with Comment to OP.